# Request help on csv file export using VBA code

Tags: vba

Request correction and understanding for the below query of csv export using VBA code.

```
Private Sub VAT_OFFSET_Click()

    strDestPtah = IIf(Right(txtDestpath.Value, 1) = "\", txtDestpath.Value, txtDestpath.Value & "\") 'Automatically add "\" at the end, if not exist

    DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acExportDelim, , TableName:="VAT_OFFSET", Filename:=strDestPtah & "GRT_OUTPUT.csv", HasFieldNames:=True

End Sub
```

Over the net I have found the below query

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "tmpExport", "C:\export.csv"
```

so as per my understanding "`tmpexport`" is the table name from where the data will be exported to csv and instead of  `C:\export.csv` I have entered the variable (`strDestPtah`) used to manually enter the path at form.

Comment: Are you receiving an error?

Comment: Yes.. its complie erro: Syntax error

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to qualify your parameter names, you don't need to leave the empty one.  So, you can either do

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "VAT_OFFSET", strDestPtah & "GRT_OUTPUT.csv", True
```

or

```
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acExportDelim, TableName:="VAT_OFFSET", Filename:=strDestPtah & "GRT_OUTPUT.csv", HasFieldNames:=True
```

Comment: Thanks and really appreciate your help Weloytty. Now its showing runtime error: 3615: Type mismatch in expression.

Comment: What did you change the code to?  You can review the parameters and what their values should be at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thanks again Weloytty..... I have not changed anything just copy pasted the above code shared by you. Does this issue has something to do with main script(query) which generates the output?